# Convert 64-bit double to int64_t in C++ similar to Convert::ToInt64 Method

Tags: c#, c++11, casting, double

Is there a function in C++ (g++ compiler) standard library (or some other library) that can convert from a double to a 64-bit integer equivalent to that provided in .NET `Convert.ToInt64` method?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fwcsf0k4(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be just a `round()` and a `cast`:

```
#include <exception>    // std::exception
#include <iostream>     // std::cout
#include <limits>
#include <cstdint>      // int64_t
#include <math.h>       // round

int main(void)
{
    double values[] = { std::numeric_limits<double>::min(), -1.38e10, -1023.299, -12.98,
                       0, 9.113e-16, 103.919, 17834.191, std::numeric_limits<double>::max() };
    int64_t result;

    for (double value : values)
    {
       try {
          result = (int64_t)round(value);
          std::cout << "Converted value '" << value << "' to value " << result << '\n';
       }
       catch (std::exception& e) {
          std::cout << value << " is outside the range of the Int64 type: " << e.what() << '\n';
       }   
    }        
}
```

Output:

```
Converted value '2.22507e-308' to value 0
Converted value '-1.38e+010' to value -13800000000
Converted value '-1023.3' to value -1023
Converted value '-12.98' to value -13
Converted value '0' to value 0
Converted value '9.113e-016' to value 0
Converted value '103.919' to value 104
Converted value '17834.2' to value 17834
Converted value '1.79769e+308' to value -9223372036854775808
```

Unlike in `Convert.ToInt64()`, range violations do not throw an exception.
Note the conversion error in the last output line.